# Bind shorter var names in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

To the risk of being closed as duplicate (I can't really find it...) I have the following question. I am sure it's either under my nose, or not possible, but I prefer to ask.

Is it possible to bind to multiple, shorter variable names in django? I know the existence of `with`, but with assumes you open a block. I would like to bind three or four, meaning that I would have to open (and close) four `with` blocks. Feasible, but not very nice.

Example, say I have this in my context: `foo.bar.baz.quux1`,  `foo.bar.baz.quux2`,  `foo.bar.baz.quux3`. I would like to bind them to `quux1`, `quux2` and `quux3` for easier access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a built-in way. You could do this in the view, or write a shortcut method on `foo`. Alternatively a [custom template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#setting-a-variable-in-the-context) could do it.

Comment: Since Django 1.3 it is possible to use mutliple variables in one with-block https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#with

Answer (score 0):

`{% with foo.bar.baz.quux3 as quux3 %}`

Comment: -1 - Read the question before answering: "Is it possible to bind to *multiple*, shorter variable names in django? I know the existence of `with`..."